# Running Bower install behind corporate proxy

Tags: javascript, npm, github-for-windows, bower-install

```
I am getting Error : 
ECONNREFUSED Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/bootstrap-datepicker failed: connect ECONNREFUSED

while running Bower Install from Package Manager Console.
I found some settings on other thread to solve this issue

{
  "directory": "library",
  "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com",
  "proxy":"http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<PROXY_IP>:<PROXY_PORT>/",
  "https-proxy":"http://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<PROXY_IP>:<PROXY_PORT>/",
}
```

Most of the people solve their problem by above mentioned setting.
My question is Which UserName and Password I need to pass in this command.
Is it my Domain Credential or something else?

Next is What will be ProxyIP and Proxy port for these settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your internet explorer settings to find out your proxy-ip (hostname) and port.  If this is set to auto-detect, type in the following adres in the browser http://wpad/wpad.dat
This downloads the configuration file of your corporate proxy server.  Open it in a text editor and you should find the hostname and port.

Then the username and password.  Do you need to type in username and password when using a browser?  If the answer is yes, use the same.  If the answer is no you probably use NTLM and you should try your windows credentials.
If that fails aswel try to prepend your username with your current domain as follows

domain\username

You can find out your domain like this:  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/find-the-domain-your-computer-belongs-to